# Lua alarm does not execute code

Tags: lua, iot, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm programming in a NodeMCU using LuaLoader. I'm trying to read the ADC of the Node and send it to a PHP file in my public domain.

With the next code I get the adc and the Node's IP and send it through GET.

```
x = adc.read(0);
ip = wifi.sta.getip();

conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 
conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) print(payload) end) 
conn:connect(80,'example.com') 
conn:send("GET /data.php?mdata="..x.."&ip="..ip.." HTTP/1.1\r\n") 
conn:send("Host: example.com\r\n") 
conn:send("Connection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n") 
conn:send("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n")
conn:send("\r\n")
print ("Done")
```

The code works correctly. If I paste this in my LuaLoader it will return:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 02:47:51 GMT
 Server: Apache
 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.26
 Content-Length: 0
 Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Content-Type: text/html

 Done
```

However, I want to repeat the code inside an alarm and send the data each minute, but it doesnt work.

```
tmr.alarm(0, 60000, 1, function()
    x = adc.read(0);
    ip = wifi.sta.getip();

    conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 
    conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) print(payload) end) 
    conn:connect(80,'example.com') 
    conn:send("GET /data.php?mdata="..x.."&ip="..ip.." HTTP/1.1\r\n") 
    conn:send("Host: example.com\r\n") 
    conn:send("Connection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n") 
    conn:send("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n")
    conn:send("\r\n")
    print ("Done")
 end )
```

The output is only...

```
 Done
```

...without the payload. It is not sending the data.

I tried putting the code in a function, in another file and calling it to the alarm with **dotfile** but it does not work. I tried giving it more time to send the data extending the alarm 2 minutes but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I added a callback when the connection is established. The alarm probably was resetting the connection before sending the package.

```
x = adc.read(0);
ip = wifi.sta.getip();

conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 
conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) 
    print ("\nDone---------------")
    print(payload)     
end)

conn:on("connection", function(conn, payload) 
   print('\nConnected...') 
   conn:send("GET /data.php?mdata="..x.."&ip="..ip.." HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        .."Host: example.com\r\n" 
        .."Connection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n"
        .."User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n"
        .."\r\n")
end)

conn:connect(80,'example.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [`tmr.alarm`](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/wiki/nodemcu_api_en#tmralarm), the 3rd argument can be `0` or `1`:

```
repeat: `0` - one time alarm, `1` - repeat
```

Since you are passing `0`, it is executing the function just once. Pass `1` instead:

```
tmr.alarm(0, 60000, 1, function()
    x = adc.read(0);
    ip = wifi.sta.getip();

    conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0) 
    conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) print(payload) end) 
    conn:connect(80,'robcc.esy.es') 
    conn:send("GET /data.php?mdata="..x.."&ip="..ip.." HTTP/1.1\r\n") 
    conn:send("Host: robcc.esy.es\r\n") 
    conn:send("Connection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n") 
    conn:send("User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; esp8266 Lua; Windows NT 5.1)\r\n")
    conn:send("\r\n")
    print ("Done")
end )
```

Comment: Yes, I tried at last moment changing it to 0, but still with 1  in the 3rd argument still it does not send anything.